# Twisted trial, PYTHONPATH and sys.path

Tags: python, twisted, pythonpath, trial, sys.path

I'm trying to reproduce example from "Test-driven development with Twisted" at http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/trial.html.

I created files:

```
calculus/__init__.py
calculus/base_1.py
calculus/test/__init__.py
calculus/test/test_base_1.py
```

I modified PYTHONPATH:

```
[xxx@zzz calculus]$ PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`/.."
```

I invoked trial:

```
[xxx@zzz twistedm]$ trial calculus.test.test_base_1
calculus
  test
    test_base_1 ...                                                     [ERROR]

===============================================================================
[ERROR]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/trial/runner.py", line 602, in loadByNames
    things.append(self.findByName(name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/trial/runner.py", line 406, in findByName
    return reflect.namedAny(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/reflect.py", line 307, in namedAny
    raise ObjectNotFound('%r does not name an object' % (name,))
twisted.python.reflect.ObjectNotFound: 'calculus.test.test_base_1' does not name an object

calculus.test.test_base_1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.199s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Python didn't find my module.

But if I invoke python shell and try to import my modules, python imports them.

I then added a line "*sys.path.append('/home/xxx/twistedm/calculus/..')*" into file "*/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/reflect.py*". And now all works as it should.

So I've found out that trial looks for modules in sys.path, and setting PYTHONPATH on command line has no effect on sys.path.

The question is how to modify sys.path from command line when invoking trial.

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
PYTHONPATH="${PWD}" trial calculus
```

Or:

```
python -m twisted.trial calculus
```

Or write a `setup.py` and install your source (into a virtualenv with `pip -e`, probably) and then just:

```
trial calculus
```

Answer (score -2):

I've just found that setting PYTHONPATH, even empty, in ~/.bashrc and then sourcing it solves the problem.

So, put a line in ~/.bashrc:

```
export PYTHONPATH=""
```

Then run a command in terminal:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now trial works even without modifying PYTHONPATH, i. e.  with empty PYTHONPATH.

Comment: "empty" PYTHONPATH means "add the current working directory to sys.path".  It's the same as PYTHONPATH=".".  And you should ***NOT*** set this in your bashrc!  For the very same reason PATH does not include "." on any modern system - because it makes you vulnerable to an attack where code in your working directory is unexpectedly executed.